# Can I replace a high limit switch myself?

Tags: hvac, heating

Thank you for the answer, can I change this myself or do I need to get the HVAC company to do this? I have turned off the breaker in the panel box so that it does not come back on. What is the purpose of a high low switch?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it yourself.

Google for "service instructions <brand and model>" of the furnace to determine where the limit switch is located.  With power disconnected, open the necessary panel(s) to assess whether it is something you would be comfortable doing.  It may require removal of the blower assembly and/or reaching past sharp and delicate heat exchanger protuberances.  Or it could be right there, front and center held in by only one simple screw.  It is well worth taking a look.

If you decide you aren't up for replacing it, you don't *have* to call an HVAC company.  Maybe you have a handy friend, relative, or neighbor?  In such a case, etiquette calls for exchanging their services and skills with a tasty drink or meal, depending upon how much you value their help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a suitable replacement part, surely you *could* replace a high limit switch yourself.  However, if you don't know much about furnaces (or HVAC systems in general), you'll likely have a difficult go of it. If you're not experienced; and don't know anybody who is that could help you, it's best to contact a professional.

A high limit switch is designed to turn off the burner (heating element), if the temperature within the furnace is too high. In most furnaces when the limit switch opens (trips), the blower will continue to run to eliminate the excess heat.  Most of the time the limit switch will reset, once the temperature has dropped enough. These devices tend to have a finite number of trips in them, before they stop resetting.

If the furnaces air filter is dirty, it can cause a restriction in the air flow through the furnace. If the air flow is reduced, not enough heat will be pulled away from the heater. The temperature within the heater will continue to raise, until it reaches the trip temperature of the limit switch.  If this happens too many times, the limit switch will eventually break.